# Show that $30 \mid (n^9 - n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

I am trying to show that $30 \mid (n^9 - n)$. I thought about using induction but I'm stuck at the induction step.

Base Case: $n = 1 \implies 1^ 9 - 1 = 0$ and $30 \mid 0$.

Induction Step: Assuming $30 \mid k^9 - k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $(k+1)^9 - (k+1) = [9k^8 + 36k^7 + 84k^6 + 126k^5 + 126k^4 + 84k^3 + 36k^2 + 9k] - (k+1)$.

However I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Why did you change 9 to k?

Comment: Oh maybe you meant $30|(n^9-n)$?

Comment: Have you consider factoring $n^9-n$ ?

Comment: You perhaps want to change your title and your body because you said you wanted to show $30 \mid (n^9 - 9)$ yet you are writing a proof showing that $30 \mid n^9 - n$.

Comment: As an alternative approach, you could look at $n^9 - n$ modulo $30$. What is the remainder of $n^9-n$ when divided by $30$ for $n = 0,\dots,29$?

Comment: Is necesary use induction?

Comment: Apologies everyone for mis-typing the question and the title. I've fixed it now.

No, I can use whatever number-theoretic means possible to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And here are the congruences requested to complement the answer by Simon S

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
n&n-1&n+1&n^2+1&n^4+1\\
\hline
0&4&1&1&1\\
1&0&2&2&2\\
2&1&3&0&4\\
3&2&4&0&2\\
4&3&0&2&2
\end{array}$$

And one can see that one of these factors is always $\equiv 0\pmod{5}$

Comment: Thank you marwalix. That is crystal clear.

Answer (score 12):

*Hint:* Note that

$$n^9 - n = n(n^8 - 1) = n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2+1)(n^4+1)$$

This expression is equal to zero mod $2$ and mod $3$, as $n-1, n, n+1$ are factors.

If you can show that at least one of these factors is divisible by $5$ you'll be done, as $2|m, 3|m, 5|m \Rightarrow 30|m$.

There are just five cases to consider $n \equiv 0,1,2,3,4 \mod 5$. For example

- if $n \equiv 0$ then the factor $n \equiv 0$
- if $n \equiv 1$ then the factor $n-1 \equiv 0$
- if $n \equiv 2$ then the factor $n^2 + 1  \equiv 0$

Comment: Okay, however how I do I show that at least one of these factors is divisible by 5? I understand how to show that it is divisible by 2 and 3 since there are three consecutive integers $S = (n-1)n(n+1)$ so $S = 2k = 2r$ for some $k, r \in \mathbb{Z}$ but I am unsure how to show it for the case of 5.

Comment: As Simon pointed out, There are only five numbers to try. Just try them.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative way of doing it:
Since $\phi(30)=8$, we get that $m^9 \equiv m \pmod{30}$ whenever $(m,30)=1$.
Since the only factors of $30$ are $2$,$3$, and $5$, we write:
$$ n=2^a \cdot 3^b \cdot 5^c \cdot m$$
Where $(m,30)=1$. Now:
$$ n^9 = 2^{9a} \cdot 3^{9b}\cdot 5^{9c} \cdot m^9 \equiv (2^9)^a \cdot (3^9)^b \cdot (5^9)^c \cdot m \pmod{30}$$
Now note: 
$$2^9 \equiv 2 \pmod{30}$$
$$3^9 \equiv 3 \pmod{30}$$
$$5^9 \equiv 5 \pmod{30}$$
So therefore: $$n^9 \equiv 2^a \cdot 3^b \cdot 5^c \cdot m \equiv n \pmod{30}$$
And therefore $30 \mid n^9-n$

Comment: The trouble that I see with this proof is that the claim that $n = 2^a . 3^b . 5^c . m$ only works if $n$ is not a prime greater than 5. For instance, this proof does not seem to me to guarantee that $7^9 - 7$ is divisible by 30 (though of course it is true).

Comment: The key thing there is to note that $(7,30)=1$, and so the the Fermat-Euler Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem) tells us that $7^8 \equiv 1 \pmod{30}$ and thus $7^9 \equiv 7 \pmod{30}$

Comment: Ah I see. So if I understand, these kinds of cases are already going to be true by Euler's Theorem.

Comment: The Fermat-Euler theorem tells us that if $(a,m)=1$, then $a^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, and since $\phi(30)=8$, the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $30=2.3.5$ so only is necesary proof that $2,3,5 \mid (n^9 - n)$ is easy see that $2\mid (n^9 - n)$, next using that $ n^3 = \,n \,mod \,3$ you get that $3\mid (n^9 - n)$ at the end using that $n^4 = \,1 \,mod \,5$ and $n^5 = n \,mod \,5$ get that $5 \mid (n^9 - n)$ and finish the proof. the best

Answer (score 1):

[Carmichael's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Exponential_cycle_length) $\lambda(30)=4$, since $4=lcm(\phi(2),\phi(3),\phi(5))$.

So for all $b\ge 1$, $a^{b+4} \equiv a^b \bmod 30$. In particular $a^9\equiv a^5\equiv a \bmod 30$, so $(a^9-a) \equiv 0 \bmod 30$, giving $30 \mid (a^9-a)$